# How to do a text search on the query set returned by a geospatial query in mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I need to find 'items' nearby matching a text. I am using mongo engine and I have tried the following.

```
Item.objects(
            location__near=[item_obj.longitude, item_obj.latitude],
            location__max_distance=item_obj.range).filter(
                Q(title__icontains=item_obj.search) |
                Q(description__icontains=item_obj.search)
            ).order_by('-like_count')
```

I get the following error

```
OperationFailure: database error: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { $and: [ { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 4.95, 4.95 ] } }, $maxDistance: 10000 } }, { $or: [ { title: /title/i }, { description: /title/i } ] } ] }
```

However the following works just fine:

```
items = Item.objects(
                location__near=[item_obj.longitude, item_obj.latitude],
                location__max_distance=item_obj.range
            )
```

Here `location` is a `PointField`

Comment: Looks to be missing the geo index - can you try: `Item.ensure_indexes()` and then run it.

Comment: Tried that but no difference. According to the manuals, PointField should set the 2d sphere index automatically. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of MongoDB / MongoEngine?

Comment: mongoengine==0.8.4
mongo v2.4.9

Comment: What does `Item._geo_indices()` output?

Comment: [{'fields': [('location', '2dsphere')]}]

Comment: strangely the same error is occurring for the working query above, but the mongo version is 2.0.4. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49074/discussion-between-ross-and-nithin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems its not using the index for the query.

1) Ensure the index is created:

```
Item.ensure_indexes()
```

2) Add a hint to the query to ensure it uses the 2dsphere index:

```
Item.objects( 
  location__near=[item_obj.longitude, item_obj.latitude], 
  location__max_distance=item_obj.range).filter( 
    Q(title__icontains=item_obj.search) | 
    Q(description__icontains=item_obj.search) 
).order_by('-like_count').hint([('location', '2dsphere')])
```